# How to detect if the user left web-chat preliminary?

Tags: botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

Basically, this is a question:
How to detect if the user left web-chat preliminary? Let's say the user closes a web page of the browser. Is there any way to catch this very moment?

Ideally, I'd like to catch an event and react to that - if such exist, but if there are any possible solutions to solve this problem - please reply.

More details - I'm using direct-line and web-chat only - there are no other channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach an event listener to the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event to trigger whatever code you want before the window closes.

Comment: Thanks, this is not what I'm looking for. Because of 2 reasons: 1 - this is not a bot but a bot host application tweak, 2 - this is not working in Chrome (any Chromium-based browser), and the only browser that supports this is Firefox. However I can not relay on this

Comment: This has had browser support since Chrome 1.0, back in 2008, and it's supported by all major browsers today.

Comment: This will allow you to send a message to the host before leaving the chat, or whatever your app is. I don't know much about the botframework, but unless it uses WebSockets I think this is your best bet. An AJAX polling mechanism will not inform the server that the client has disconnected.

Comment: Here, you can use [WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)